# Gmail - Notificación de vencimiento de factura

Tags: gmail

Hace un tiempo, mi correo electrónico "info@x.com" fue aprobado para el marcado de Gmail. En nuestra empresa enviamos facturas para pagar a nuestros clientes y estas facturas tienen fecha de vencimiento. Lo que buscaba es que el día que expire la factura, nuestros clientes reciban una notificación a traves del asistente de Google de que su factura vence hoy, como en las siguientes imagen:

[image: Notificación 1]
[image: Notificación 2]

Resulta que esta notificación no llega a mis clientes, ya revisé el marcado y es correcto, cumplo con todos los requisitos que me pidieron, pero no puedo recibir esa notificación. Si pudiera ayudarme y decirme si este servicio depende del marcado de gmail, se lo agradecería mucho, gracias.

Comment: Gmail Markup - https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup

Comment: Revisa la doc sobre [`Invoice`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/invoice).

Comment: Si, ya lo revise, mande la solicitud a Google y aprobaron mi email.

Comment: Pero no entiendo el problema que tienes ni en qué contexto exactamente ¿?

Comment: Que la notificación del vencimiento de la factura no aparece en ningún celular. Y supuestamente desde Google me respondieron que la notificación si se tendría que mostrar. El marcado del email es correcto, verificado por Google. Lo que me a pensar de que esa notificación no depende de Gmail Markup.